# Woocommerce product editor does not add br

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

When I add content to woocommerce product editor, it does not add br (new line), when I push the enter key, so the content on the website is in one line. Any ideas, how to resolve this issue? I changed the theme and I turn off the plugins, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing in the 'text' editor and adding `&nbsp;` on the empty lines and see if that gets stripped out.

**Update:**
Here's a screen capture, yeah it gets stripped out because of WordPress' default formatting ([wpautop](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/)), but it still registers what was intended.  Here's the text:
[image: TEXT editor]

Now here's the end result on the front end:
[image: Front end view]

There must be something stripping out your formatting either from the theme or some plugin.

Comment: Yes, but the client would like to edit by himself so I cant say to him to add &nbsp; in text editor.

Comment: I understand that but as a troubleshooting method it'd be nice to see if that works or not.

I'd even go so far as to test it by wrapping text in <p> tags, then manually adding <br/> tags in addition to what I suggested above.  See if it strips those elements out.  It could be a setting in the themes you're using.  Also, is this for the product short description or the long description?

Comment: So I've already tested and I tried to add &nbsp; and <p> tags in text editor, but if I switched to visual, all tags disappeared. It is long descripton (textarea below title)